# WithDraw money From an Account (Java)

Tags: java

I'm doing the exercise (3.11) from Deital How to Program 10th Edition there is no error in my program but i want that when the withdraw money is greater then balance then it should show only "Insufficient Balance" message, it should not show the balance amount kindly help me i'm just a beginner.

that is my main program

```
package practice;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class apple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        tuna account1 = new tuna ("James" , 150000);
        tuna account2 = new tuna ("David" , 5000);
        System.out.printf("%s Balance: %.2f" , account1.getName(),account1.getBalance());
        System.out.printf("%n%s Balance: %.2f" , account2.getName(), account2.getBalance());
        System.out.print("\nEnter the Ammount that will add in James Account: ");
        double depositAmmount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("Adding %.2f to James Account", depositAmmount);
        account1.deposit(depositAmmount);
        System.out.printf("%n%s Balance: %.2f" , account1.getName(),account1.getBalance());
        System.out.print("\nEnter the Ammount that will add in David Account: ");
        depositAmmount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("Adding %.2f to David Account", depositAmmount);
        account2.deposit(depositAmmount);
        System.out.printf("%n%s Balance: %.2f" , account2.getName(),account2.getBalance());
        System.out.print("\nEnter the Ammount that will withdrawal from james Account: ");
        double wD = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("WithDrawal %.2f from James Account",wD);
        account1.withDrawal(wD);
        System.out.printf("%n%s Balance: %.2f" , account1.getName(),account1.getBalance());
    }
        }
```

and that is the class

```
package practice;

public class tuna {
private String name;
private double balance;
public tuna (String name , double balance){
    this.name = name;
    if (balance > 0)
        this.balance = balance;
}
public void deposit(double depositAmmount){
    if (depositAmmount > 0)
        balance = balance + depositAmmount;
}
public void withDrawal (double wD){
    if (wD > balance)
        System.out.println("\nInsufficient Balance");
    else 
    balance = balance - wD;
}
public double getBalance(){
    return balance;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
}
```

Comment: So what is the exact issue? I guess you want to know if the `withDrawal` function actually modified the `balance` variable? In that case you could (for example) have it return a `boolean` (`true` if it withdrew, `false` if not) and check for that (and print a different line depending on that)

Comment: i just want when the withdrawal money is greater then balance then it shows just "Insufficient Balance" message not the amount of that account

Comment: Yes, that is what my suggestion would allow you to do. Otherwise you could also move the print statement into the `if` branch of the `withDrawal` function (which is an uglier solution IMO, I'd go with returning a `boolean`)

Comment: can you please write the code for withdrawal

Comment: Normally I wouldn't, as this is really basic stuff. But I'll make an execption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one possible solution is to have the function return a `boolean` indicating whether it succeeded or not:

```
public boolean withDrawal (double wD){
    if (wD > balance) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        balance = balance - wD;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
if(account1.withDrawal(wD)) {
   System.out.printf("%n%s Balance: %.2f" , account1.getName(),account1.getBalance());
}
else {
   System.out.println("\nInsufficient Balance");
}
```